# How to check overlap date time with specific time SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I using postgresSql and i want check overlap date in specific datetime, not range date time.

Example :

I have booking room two time  and it booking every saturday :

```
StartTime                EndTime
2019-08-10 00:00:00      2019-08-20 03:00:00
```

I only want check datetime every saturday(startTime + 7 days) every week. If I put time look like :

```
StartTime                EndTime
2019-08-17 00:00:00      2019-08-17 03:00:00
```

it overlaps . If i put time :

```
StartTime                EndTime
2019-08-16 00:00:00      2019-08-16 03:00:00
```

it not overlaps.

If i using command sql look like :

```
SELECT (TIMESTAMP '2019-08-10 00:00:00', TIMESTAMP '2019-08-10 03:00:00') OVERLAPS (TIMESTAMP '2019-08-10 01:00:00',TIMESTAMP '2019-08-20 01:00:00')
```

It check all date in range time: 2019-08-10 -> 2019-08-20 and throw overlaps . I only want check 2019-08-10 an 2019-08-17 and throw overlaps. If date 2019-08-11,2019-08-12,2019-08-13,2019-08-14,2019-08-15,2019-08-16,2019-08-18,2019-08-19,2019-08-20 it not overlaps. How to do that.

It same question it monthly. Please help ?

Comment: . . Your question is unclear.  I suspect that you want to know if or how many Saturdays are during the stay (based on the comments below).  If that is your question, then ask a *new* question, be clear on the explanation and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

You may add an additional condition If at least one Saturday falls in the given range

```
SELECT 
(TIMESTAMP '2019-08-10 00:00:00', TIMESTAMP '2019-08-10 03:00:00') 
  OVERLAPS 
(TIMESTAMP '2019-08-10 01:00:00', TIMESTAMP '2019-08-20 01:00:00') AND
EXISTS ( 
 select 1 from generate_series( 
         TIMESTAMP '2019-08-10 00:00:00', 
         TIMESTAMP '2019-08-10 03:00:00',
         INTERVAL '1 DAY'
         ) as dt  where extract(isodow from dt ) = 6
   )                            --ISO day of the week
```

Comment: Thanks you.If it month how to i handle it. Because some month : example :  February it had 28 or 29 day but with August it had 31 days and September it had 30 day

Comment: @trungdn92 : I don't understand your question. `generate_series` generates dates when  date arguments are passed and not numbers. So, only valid dates are generated and invalid dates like Feb 29 on a non-leap year or September 31 won't ever appear in the generated dates.